# Search in list with link ignore case sensitive

Tags: c#, search

I need to do is search that search of list of string and if I put for example

String like ***N or name or na*** I will get all the following entries

How should I do that?

I try with the following code which is not working fine if the word

```
myname
name
name1
NAME
n 
N
Run 



SearchValue = (from stp in SearchValue where stp.Description.Contains(_searchString) select stp).ToList<Serv>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `IndexOf` + `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnorecase`:

```
SearchValue = SearchValue 
    .Where(sv => sv.Description.IndexOf(_searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks tim when I run it got error Error 9 'System.StringComparer' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentCultureIgnorecase' any idea?

Comment: @JohnJerrby: i should have tested it first, `CurrentCultureIgnorecase`  must be `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. You should also use the string-method `IndexOf` in this case with a `StringComparison` (edited).

Comment: HI tim I just found bug that if I put the first string for search ,I dont get any value in SearchValue ,any idea? I see that the index is >= 0

Comment: HI Tim , maybe something is missing since for some word I get search success (list) and for some i dont ,what can be the problem?

Comment: @JohnJerrby: "the first string" means the first string in SearchValue? Can you edit your question to include a small, reproducible sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains` which supports case-insensitive comparison:

```cs
SearchValue = SearchValue 
    .Where(sv => sv.Description.Contains(_searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```

If you want a culture-aware comparison, you can use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: HI Eli , I tried to use you code and sometimes its works (for some strings) and sometimes not for the same list,any idea?